# How to Identify button state(normal/loading) using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

> After clicking this button via. selenium, the button starts loading as shown. The site is https://quillbot.com/

[image]

> Button Loading :
> [image]

> This is the button HTML code :

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained QuillButton-sc-12j9igu-0 dkavuo quillArticleBtn jss1419 MuiButton-containedPrimary" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label"><div class="jss1421">Paraphrase</div><div class="jss1425" style="opacity: 0; transition: opacity 1100ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms; visibility: hidden;"></div></span></button>
```

> After the loading/processing, the button is changed back to its normal state.

> I know, this is something to do with JavaScript, how can I know when the button is finished loading ? I am basically trying to automate the entire process

Comment: There is a html tag underneath it which changes styles which you can check for if you want to.

Comment: how ? can you please elaborate a little bit , pls

Comment: Check the answer if that works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it without use of JavaScript or any additional to Selenium tools and skills.
The "Rephrase" button itself classes are changing between the states.
While the rephrasing process the button element contains several additional class names. One of them is `Mui-disabled`  .
So to indicate the rephrasing process is complete / not running now you can validate as following:

```py
self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'QuillButton') and(not(contains(@class,'Mui-disabled')))]")))
```

Comment: Oh didn't spot the mui disabled. This xpath would be much better.

Comment: "self" is not defined , how to fix this Sir ?

Comment: It depends on actual structure of your code. Please share the actual structure of your Selenium project and I will try to give you a better answer.

Comment: I see no code there

Comment: I see no new information details in your question. Do you mean you changed your code so now my answer resolved your question?

Comment: your answer worked upto yesterday but from yesterday on, it doesnt work. Can you help me please

Comment: This means that you have changed something in your code... Please open a new question for that

Answer (score 1):

So basically when you get to the site you send the keys to the div tag. Click the rephrase button and then wait for the element to come back. I just used time to check if there was any difference on the load.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
driver.get('https://quillbot.com/')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#inputText"))).send_keys("This is a test")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#InputBottomQuillControl > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div > button"))).click()
print(time.perf_counter())
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@style='opacity: 0; transition: opacity 1100ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms; visibility: hidden;']")))
print(time.perf_counter())
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
```

Comment: it suddently stopped working, upto yesterday it worked great ! can you please check once. pls

Comment: I fixed it buddy, had to use this : w.switch_to.window(w.window_handles[-1])

Comment: So it opened a new window.

Comment: yes, exactly. The code was executing to the older tab, I just had to focus on the current tab